# Strange substance in PCB soldering (corrosion?)

Tags: pcb, corrosion

After about 8 month since the electronic components were soldered to a PCB using Pb-free tin, a strange substance appeared in some of the contacts (see attached image)

[image].

The PCB may have been exposed (OR NOT) to some humidity but not to other substances during its working time

What could such substance be? Would it cause short-circuit between the component pins?

It looks like some mold. But why there?

Comment: Hard to say; I *do* know that SAC solder corrosion is galvanic in nature when exposed to high humidity and some available impurities (dissimilar metal corrosion).

Comment: That looks a lot like mold or silk. Evidence of insects or moisture?

Comment: Any chance you could get us a closer up (or microscope) image?

Comment: @hekete yes, it looks like mold. But what caused to appear there?

Comment: Some kinds of solder flux can get fun chemical reactions with whatever else might be present. I had something similar myself recently, where some RoHS flux reacted with silicone and created a strange white powder all over the place.

Comment: Do you use some manner of PCB lacquer on the boards?

Comment: Soldering flux is generally made from some mix of organic compounds. It can also leave a sticky residue which can hold moisture and other contaminants. Mold spores could land in it and find it a nice place to grow. If that is what happened, then I would guess there was a lot of excess flux around those parts. Did you use anything to clean the board after soldering? If it was corrosion or some other chemical reaction I would expect it to look more crystalline rather than organic.

Answer (score -1):

Clean it off with [flux remover](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-1-d&ei=S973XMeiAoOsswWa47eADQ&q=flux%20remover%20techspray&oq=flux%20remover%20te), then look at the pins and see if they are corroded (material removed or pockmarks). If it is corroded then the chip might be toast.